# SlickGrid keyboard navigation on headers

Tags: header, navigation, keyboard, slickgrid, keyevent

Is there a way to do SlickGrid keyboard navigation on frozen headers?  I have a slick grid spreadsheet and can use the keyboard arrows inside the context.  Now I want to use the keyboard arrows inside the  top and left headers

Comment: I assume you are referring to the [6pac/SlickGrid](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid) fork. Keyboard navigations was never implemented for the header titles, only in the grid, it would probably require lot of work to include the headers... but this is an Open Source project, if you want something well you know what to do.. Contribute :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Exactly!!!  I referred to the  [6pac/SlickGrid](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid)   fork.  So according to your answer,   I will do it by myself.  thanks a lot 

Comment: I meant to say that this feature does not currently exist, but if you find a way to do it, you can contribute to the lib by creating a Pull Request. I added a lot of features (mostly plugins) myself.